# Doctrine2 - How to add custom DBAL driver?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, odbc, dbal

In my symfony 3.3.2 project , I want to connect to sage database using odbc sage.
I create a new dsn named : GestCom_Sage100.

I tried to connect to this dataSource using symfony but I got this error :

```
The given 'driver' SAGE Gestion commeriale 100 is unknown, Doctrine currently 
supports only the following drivers: pdo_mysql, pdo_sqlite, pdo_pgsql, 
pdo_oci, oci8, ibm_db2, pdo_sqlsrv, mysqli, drizzle_pdo_mysql, sqlanywhere, 
sqlsrv
```

here is my config.yml:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            driver: pdo_pgsql
            host: '%database_host%'
            port: '%database_port%'
            dbname: '%database_name%'
            user: '%database_user%'
            password: '%database_password%'
            charset: UTF8                
        sage:
            driver: SAGE Gestion commeriale 100
            host: 'localhost'
            dbname: 'GestCom_Sage100'
            user: '****'
            password: '*****'
```

Even Doctrine2 documentation http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#pdo-oci-oci8

Comment: `SAGE Gestion commeriale 100` is not valid driver, you shall use driver from the list that corresponds to this database.

Comment: Sounds like you need pdo_odbc though you probably need to install it: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php

Answer (score -1):

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:         YOUR_DRIVER
        driver_class:  YOUR_DRIVER_CLASS_NAMESPACE
```

Comment: Can you add any explanation regarding why this solves the problem?